# Vertical Alignment Within Itemized List

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

I am having trouble aligning text within an enumerated list.  For example, in the following, I would like the *(text_to_align1)*, *(text_to_align2)*, and *(text_to_align3)* align vertically to each other.  As a note, phrase1,2,3, and (text_to_align1,2,3) are short enough so that they can finish within one line but are of different lengths.

```
    \item phrase1 (text_to_align1)
    \item phrase2 (text_to_align2)
    \item phrase3 (text_to_align3)
```

Comment: The strings `(text_to_align1)`, `(text_to_align2)`, `(text_to_align3)` may have different widths, right? If so, how should they be aligned relative to each other? Specifically, should they share the same centerline, or should ether the strings' starting points or end points be aligned vertically? Please advise.

Comment: Thank you for your question.  The strings' starting points should align vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\settowidth{\mylen}{phraseXXX} % measure width of longest "phrase" string
    \item \mybox{phraseX} (text-to-align1)
    \item \mybox{phraseXX} (text-to-align22)
    \item \mybox{phraseXXX} (text-to-align333)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```